# how can I draw a Table view programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to draw a table view programitacllay b/c I face one problem, and the problem is that I have two views , whenever the sencond view is come the table view will be drawn downside, and when this view disable the table view is drawn upside...

How can I resolve it...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of your question. What do you mean by "draw a table programatically" and "drawn downside"? Please edit your question so that we can a) understand what you're talking about and b) help you solve the problem. Be warned, though: it's never a good idea to subvert Cocoa Touch's view drawing system, and if that's what you're trying to do it's a clear sign that there's a problem in your code.

Comment: I think a screenshot would go a long way to explain what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some event to draw second view? If so then in that you will need to set the center of tableView using method .......`[yourTableView setCenter:[coord where you want it to be]];` ... just detect the seconds views presence either by setting its tag to some value and then checking whether a view with that tag is available than adjust the position of tableview

`[secondView setTag:2];` //somewhere you create secondView......

in the event ......

```
if([self.view viewWithTag:2]!=nil{//i am considering you have added views on self.view.
  //second view exists

}
else{
//second view is not there.....
}
```

Thanks,